# How to get a mobile image to hide in Gmail?

Tags: html, css, mobile, gmail

I know that gmail strips the embedded code in the header, which carries the media queries. I want to have one image show on desktop, and another show on mobile. In Gmail, on desktop, both images show.

I managed to get it to the point that in Gmail, the mobile image shows on top of the content below (instead of pushing it down), but then adding `visibility: hidden` to the CSS and inline, as well as `position: absolute` but this did not make it disappear!

How do I hide the mobile image in Gmail desktop?

This is what I have:

**CSS:**

```
 `@media (min-width: 481px) {
          .mobileShow {
    display: none;
    font-size: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -999999;
}
          .mobileHide { display: inline-block; }
      }
     @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .mobileShow {
        display:block !important;
        line-height: 1.5 !important;
        max-height: none !important;
        visibility: visible !important;
        position: relative; !important;
        z-index: 100 !important;
        opacity: 100 !important;
    }
        .mobileHide { display: none;}`
```

**Inline:**

```
<div class="mobileHide">
                <img class="banner" src="header.jpg" border="0"     alt="" height="auto" />
              </div>
              <div class='mobileshow' style='display:none; visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; font-size: 0; max-height: 0; line-height: 0; padding: 0;'>
                <img class="banner" src="Header-Mobile.jpg" border="0" alt="" height="auto" /></a>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove attribute style from div with class mobileshow.

You have a typo in the code. Change class name from mobileshow to mobileShow.